# PHP, different destination adding files to .zip?

Tags: php, zip

Okay let me explain. I have two folders on my server, let's say they're called f1/ and f2/.
Both folders have several files. I'd like to ZipArchive both folders. However, the best I can do is getting the .zip to contain both folders. What I want is to take all the files and folders WITHIN both f1/ and f2/ and archive them, thus having the content of f1/ and f2/ in the root of the .zip, not the two folders.

This is the code I'm currently using, which, like I said, doesn't do what I want:

```
$zipname = 'ZipArc.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($array as $file => $value)
{
    $zip->addFile("f1/" . $file . ".ini");
}

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("f2/Data/"));
    foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {
        $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key);
    }
}
$zip->close();
```

I've searched and searched, but I can't seem to hit the right keywords to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs closer: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

```
bool ZipArchive::addFile($filename, $localname, ....)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

so

```
$zip->addFile('/real/path/on/your/server/file.txt', '/path/within/zip/foo.bar');
```

Comment: Would you mind backing a bit away? I'm going to face-palm myself so hard the shockwave might kill you. Thanks man.